# How to resolve X-Frame-Options header is missing in Angular while using IFRAME inside a component

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am using angular V 15 and in one of my routes i have IFRAME  with [src] attribute to different domain.
i got the error ( chrome v 103)
`Refused to display 'http://localhost:9887/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

i used DOMsanitizer and the correct CSP . and it remove all the CSP errors that the browser (chorme 103) throw. but after all that when i use 'ng serve' i have one last error .

i also user proxy.conf.json - but it can set only the header of request and not the response.( am i wrong ?)  - some one know how to set the 'X-Frame-Options' to allowall on response with ng serve?

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove X-Frame-Options from headers by configuring the server where the external resource is hosted.

However, if you need to open sites in iframes for internal tooling, experimentation purposes, or development, you could use a tool to do this job, like fiddler, or a browser extension.

For fiddler these are the steps:

```js
1.Open Fiddler menu > Rules > Customize Rules (this effectively edits CustomRules.js).
2.Find the function OnBeforeResponse
3.Add the following lines:

Session.oResponse.headers.Remove("X-Frame-Options");
Session.oResponse.headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
4.Save the script
```

Or angular proxy config:

```js
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://your-target-url.com",
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "secure": false,
    "headers": {
      "x-frame-options": "ALLOWALL"
    }
  }
}
```